# How can I use .htaccess to mix a node & PHP application on one server with the same domain?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, .htaccess, nuxt.js

I've got a PHP application, using OpenCart, but I want to serve some of the pages as a Nuxt app. I want to keep the Nuxt app in a separate directory, but serve it only for some URLs, and let OpenCart serve the other URLs.

For example, I want:

domain.com/anvils to be served by OpenCart

domain.com/acme to be served by Nuxt

I want all the Nuxt files to be stored in /public_html/nuxt/. OpenCart serves files from /public_html/. But I don't want the /nuxt/ folder to be part of the URL, it's just for my own organisation. I want to be able to use .htaccess to redirect the URLs that I choose to the Nuxt app and let it do the routing.

At the moment my .htaccess has this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I point URLs that I want to the Nuxt application?

Comment: Well, you add an internal rewriting rule to your existing rules. That rule captures requests to a static URL prefix, something like `/app/` and rewrites them into the folder where that nuxt application lives. You add that rule as an exception to the existing rules, so _before_ those, so further up in the configuation.

Comment: Great. How do I do that?

Comment: I wonder however whether that app is a node based application as you suggest with the title of this question or an app based on the nuxt library as you say in the description.

Comment: How to do what? Implement a rewriting rule? You already have four in your file. So I assume you know how to do that.

Comment: Ahh this file came from OpenCart, I didn't write it. So I don't know how to write a rule routing one URL to a particular file. It's an app based on the Nuxt library, which runs on Node.

Comment: I am used to Node being operated as a separate http server which in such mixed setups is hidden behind a front http server proxying requests to the node server. You discribe things different, as if you just want to internally rewrite requets to that folder inside the front http server...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it would make sense to move the implementation of that OpenCart solution into an own folder beside the folder for the Nuxt application. That would allow for a cleaner separation between the two. Especially it would mean that the rewriting configuration for both solutions would be separate apart from an initial separation rule.

In that setup you could simply use two `Alias` directives inside the http server's central (virtual) host configuration:

```
Alias /anvils /public_html/opencart
Alias /acme /public_html/nuxt
```

The existing files of the OpenCard solution have to be moved into the "opencart" folder (or however you want to call that). Also the ".htaccess" configuration file needs to go there, and the `RewriteBase` needs to point to `/anvils`, I'd say. No idea how your setup works now, I'd say you currently contradict yourself in the question, since it is unclear from your question whether that OpenCart solution lives under the path `/` or `/anvils`.

This obviously is only possible if you actually have control of the host configuration, so if you operate the http server yourself. If you are using a cheap hosting provider this might not be an option for you.

---

If you want to keep the file system layout as sketched in the question then a single `Alias` Directive *might* work, you'd have to test that though:

```
Alias /acme /public_html/nuxt
```

That directive would have to be implemented *before* (so further up) in the configuration. Again this would have to be in the central host configuration, this is not possible inside a ".htaccess" file.

---

If both approaches are not possible you'd indeed have to rely on rewriting. So for what you ask this probably is a starting point:

I assume that folder "public_html" is what is configured as `DocumentRoot` in your http server's host configuration, wherever that folder is actually located inside your file system. Probably something like `/var/www/public_html` or similar. I further assume that you are using an apache http server in a recent version.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Nuxt application
RewriteRule ^/?acme(.*)$ /nuxt$1 [L]

# OpenCart auto generated rule set
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am not sure how the requests to `/anvils` are handled by that OpenCart solution. Since your current setup does not contain any traces of handling that I will leave that as it is. You need to sort that out yourself.

You need to take care that this implementation does not simply get overwritten by that OpenCart solution, you mentioned it auto generated your ".htaccess" file.

---

Disclaimer: Please note that I did not test what I suggest here. The suggestion certainly might contain typos or other glitches. Also I said above that you have to test if that actually works. And you certainly have to adjust the implementation to your specific setup. That is a general aspect of answers on SO: we are not here to do your work for you, we are here to *help* which means you need to understand what we offer instead of blindly copying some lines. You need to be able to actually use the tools you want to use, that includes testing, experimenting, debugging and reading the documentation, maybe some tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the:
RewriteRule ^/?acme(.*)$ /nuxt$1 [L]
But now when someone visits domain.com/acme it rewrites the URL to domain.com/nuxt. But I want the URL to stay as domain.com/acme but instead to server the files from /nuxt. Is that possible?

Comment: The rewriting rule is not responsible for that. This sounds as if your application logic performes a redirection, though that is only a guess on my side. Take a look into the network console of your browser and check in detail what response to your test request you get. Maybe you want to add that information to your question.